# No action clicking on Submit button in the bootstrap modal

Tags: html, post, bootstrap-modal

I have the following modal and when user clicks on Submit, I want to redirect to another page.

My HTML Code:

```
 <!-- Modal -->
       <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
           <h4 class="modal-title">Add new card</h4>
          </div>
           <form action="addCard" method="post" id="addcard" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
           <div class="modal-body" style="height: 190px;">
             <div class="form-group" style="height: 30px;">
            <label for="title" class="col-md-3 control-label">Title</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Enter Card title here...">
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group" style="height: 30px; margin-bottom:30px;">
            <label for="title" class="col-md-3 control-label">Description</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
               <textarea class="form-control" name="desc" placeholder="Enter Card description here..."></textarea>
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
            <label for="priority" class="col-md-3 control-label">Priority</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
               <select name="priority" class="form-control">
                <option value="critical">Critical</option>
                <option value="high">High</option>
                <option value="normal">Normal</option>
                <option value="low">Low</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="formSubmit" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
          </form>
         </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

app.js:

```
app.post('/addCard', routes.addCard);
```

index.js:

```
 exports.addCard = function (req,res)
  {
 res.render('index'); 
  }
```

When I click on 'Submit' button of the modal, no action is happening. Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `<form action="addCard"...` try `<form action="/addCard"....`

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. But no luck.. :(

Comment: Are you using a web framework?

Comment: Try to use `res.render('index.html')`?

Comment: Its not even redirecting in the url. So, no action is happening clicking on Submit.

Answer (score 0):

in

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="formSubmit" type="submit">Submit</button>`

you have type=button ,and then type=submit

remove type=button

Comment: My bad, but even after removing type=button, no luck.

Comment: when I replicated it, it was working for me.. do you see any errors in the Console in Chrome/Firefox/Firebug? do you see the Post even executing on your end?